How to install kerberos client in docker based on Ubuntu Focal image
I tried following docker command in docker file
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y krb5-user libpam-krb5

but it stuck expecting interaction from the use, even when i used -y switch.
12:28:58  #13 3.480 Setting up krb5-config (2.6ubuntu1) ...
12:28:58  #13 3.555 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
12:28:58  #13 3.555 debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
12:28:58  #13 3.555 debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
12:28:58  #13 3.580 Configuring Kerberos Authentication
12:28:58  #13 3.580 -----------------------------------
12:28:58  #13 3.580 
12:28:58  #13 3.580 When users attempt to use Kerberos and specify a principal or user name without
12:28:58  #13 3.580 specifying what administrative Kerberos realm that principal belongs to, the
12:28:58  #13 3.580 system appends the default realm.  The default realm may also be used as the
12:28:58  #13 3.580 realm of a Kerberos service running on the local machine.  Often, the default
12:28:58  #13 3.580 realm is the uppercase version of the local DNS domain.
12:28:58  #13 3.580 


what do i missing ?
I tired using apt-get -y switch, and i will expect it will install the package without user input

This seems like a question about setting up a Linux system; questions about the APT package manager aren't usually about programming per se and might be better asked on another site like [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].  A Docker container does not run an interactive user login system and PAM plugins aren't usually useful, your application should not need libpam-krb5.
